# Cookie "domain" does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value

Tags: php, session

I'm having a host of issues with PHP's SESSION and I'm not sure what started it all.

I was setting session_start in my code and things were working fine. I added some AJAX functionality then noticed that the session was empty for that particular call. Believing that I was starting the session too late or that maybe I forgot to include it in a page, I removed ALL instances of session_start and put one session_start in my bootstrap. So now my entire code base only has one session_start call and it's the very first line in the application.

This introduced a new issue. Now I am seeing this in dev tools:

> Cookie "PHPSESSIONID" does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value.
> Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid
> value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no
> longer be sent in third-party contexts.

I understand this has to do with SSL but this site doesn't need SSL, and I'm not even sure why I'm getting this warning. Can someone tell me what I need to do to permanently configure my code so I don't have to worry about this warning anymore? Without running SSL of course, because that's not an option.

Comment: _"I understand this has to do with SSL"_ - not really; not directly at least. If the `SameSite` value was `None`, _then_ `Secure` would also have to be set, otherwise the cookie will be rejected.

Comment: _"Can someone tell me what I need to do to permanently configure my code so I don't have to worry about this warning anymore?"_ - you need to _specify_ which `SameSite` value you want to use, instead of implicitly letting it fall back onto the default value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not even sure why I'm getting this warning.

Me neither :) Btw `setcookie` documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
<?php
$arr_cookie_options = array (
                'expires' => time() + 60*60*24*30, 
                'path' => '/', 
                'domain' => '.example.com', // leading dot for compatibility or use subdomain
                'secure' => true,     // or false
                'httponly' => true,    // or false
                'samesite' => 'None' // None || Lax  || Strict
                );
setcookie('TestCookie', 'The Cookie Value', $arr_cookie_options);    
?>
```

Did the warning disappear after you set the `samesite` option?